# Como criar um projeto baseado em Laravel para ser a base dos outros?

Tags: laravel, git, composer

Minha idéia é criar um painel administrativo base, onde posso utilizar nos próximos sites, sem precisar copiar e colar. Na base tenho apenas o controle de usuários e menus, o resto vou criando pacotes e requerer a cada novo site só o necessário. Está tudo no packagist com webhook configurado.
Então ao criar um novo site, eu faço:

```
composer create-project meuusuario/meucms novo_projeto
```

Até ai tudo bem, mas não consigo deixar os outros projetos dependentes do base.

Por exemplo: se eu mudei algo na base, outros vão atualizar via composer update. Isso é possível?

Comment: É mais fácil a base ser uma dependência do seu projeto baseado em Laravel, não?

Comment: Entendi, provavelmente vou ter que fazer dessa forma mesmo. Valeu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você mesmo apontou, criar um projeto que será utilizado como base não irá criar uma dependência com a base inicial. O repositório será clonado e atualizações posteriores precisam ser feitas manualmente. O próprio repositório da [aplicação base do Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) utiliza esse fluxo, onde o que mudou a partir do momento que você criou o projeto não será aplicado automaticamente.

Esse tipo de fluxo é legal caso seu painel já esteja maduro e não sofrerá tantas alterações assim.

Caso contrário, o melhor a se fazer é criar um *package* externo para esse projeto e utilizá-lo como dependência, assim o código do painel será atualizável a partir de um `composer update`.